# puppeteer querySelector is not a valid selector

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, webautomation

I have a code as following:

```
page.click('div.button-table div:contains(Who) div.square-button:nth-child(1)')
```

When puppeteer run this code, it will raise error:

Brief

`Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'div.button-table div:contains(Who) div.square-button:nth-child(1)' is not a valid selector.`

Full

```
 Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'div.button-table div:contains(Who) div.square-button:nth-child(1)' is not a valid selector.
at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:1:33
  at ExecutionContext.evaluateHandle (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/ExecutionContext.js:124:13)
  at <anonymous>
-- ASYNC --
  at ExecutionContext.<anonymous> (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:144:27)
  at ElementHandle.$ (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/ExecutionContext.js:529:50)
  at ElementHandle.<anonymous> (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:145:23)
  at Frame.$ (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:456:34)
  at <anonymous>
-- ASYNC --
  at Frame.<anonymous> (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:144:27)
  at Frame.click (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:735:31)
  at Frame.<anonymous> (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:145:23)
  at Page.click (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:973:29)
  at Proxy.fillInAudience (libs/page/brand_create_quote_page.js:67:21)
  at Proxy.<anonymous> (libs/logger.js:38:27)
  at Context.it (ui/brand/create_quote_spec.js:53:16)
  at <anonymous>
```

But this selector can run successfully in Devtools - `$('div.button-table div:contains(Who) div.square-button:nth-child(1)').text()`

I also figure out if I remove `div:contains(Who)`, puppeteer can run it without panic.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe because you use jQuery selector :contains https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ and there is no jQuery in puppeteer. So it's not native DOM selector, that's why puppeteer crashes

Comment: @Grynets Thanks for the remind. I think that's the cause !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Puppeteer is using [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) internally. So you would be able to use any [CSS Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors). The problem here is that [contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) is not a CSS Selector but a JQuery feature.

The good thing is that you could test your selectors using the Chrome developer tools and test them using `document.querySelector`.